# Proper way for returning XML validation failure info in restful responses using jersey

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb, jersey

I'm using jersey 2.19 with a custom ContextResolver such that an 
unmarshaller is created with a schema to validate against.  The 
validation then occurs during POST/PUT, and if fails a
BadRequestException is thrown. The client only sees 'BadRequest' in the response.
This BadRequestException contains an UnmarshalException as its cause which in turn has a linked XMLMarshalExcpetion enclosing a SAXParseException.
This SAXParseException finally holds the validation message I want to return to the clients.
I wonder what is the proper way for doing this as digging in the Exceptions chain of causes and linked exceptions does not seem right to me.
Except that it is ugly, it is implementation dependent and may change as jersey/jaxb versions change. So I want a clearer solution.

Moreover I tried setting the `ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE` to true in my `web.xml` file like this:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>package1:package2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

But still with no success.

Comment: We have not (yet) found a better solution than digging the details out of the exception chain. It is ugly.

Comment: Asserting that you call the unmarshaller in your custom ContextResolver and initiate the unmarshalling you could catch the exception there, "dig" your message and throw a custom exception with the given message on your own. You can't get rid of the digging, but you could hide it at this single location.